# aws lambda not picking up credentials with role has AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Aws Lambda not picking up credentials even after attaching a role to lambda that has AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole. I added few more logs to check if its trying to load SharedIniFileCredentials but it didnt.

### Code

```
 start: async (startParams) => {
    logger.info(startParams);
    if (startParams === konstants.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT) {
      logger.info('load credentials only for local');
      AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials();
    }
```

### Log

```
message: 'Missing credentials in config',
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  path: '/home/sbx_user1051/.aws/credentials',
  time: 2020-03-04T03:55:47.923Z,
  originalError:
   { message: 'Could not load credentials from SharedIniFileCredentials',
     errno: -2,
     syscall: 'open',
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docs [write](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-lambda.html):

> The execution role provides the Lambda function with the  credentials it needs to run and to invoke other web services.  As a result, **you do not need to provide credentials to the  Node.js** code you write within a Lambda function.

So I think you should re-think how are you writing your node.js lambda function.